# Launch snap apps from bash

Tags: snap

Trying to launch a snap app i.e. sublime-text from bash and ideally zshell but they are not found.

I've performed a `$ snap list`

Which gives:

`sublime-text   3211  85    stable    snapcrafters  classic`

However, this doesn't relate to a runable command. .

Attempts:

`subl: command not found`

`sublime-text: command not found`

Comment: Is `/snap/bin` in your user's `PATH`?

Comment: that's what I needed! Please make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up a new Ubuntu system and login as a user the directory `/snap/bin` does not exist. This path will be created once you install your first snap package with the snap package's commands symlinked. To be able to execute those symlinked commands you need to have `/snap/bin` included in your session's `PATH` environment variable.

There is a shell script at `/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh` that will add the `/snap/bin` into your `PATH` when it is parsed at login. However, it requires that the `/snap/bin` directory to already exist when your session is started.

The easiest way, therefore, to get everything correctly set-up is to install a snap, and then log-out and back into a new session. This will set your `PATH` appropriately and will continue to do so every time you login in the future.

Comment: I didn't experience this. I rebooted many times and the /snap/bin never showed in my path. I had to manually add it for the snap app to be runable via terminal (intellij and sublime text were my cases).

Answer (score 0):

easy

`cd $REPO_DIRECTORY/usr/local; games/openspades` or

`cd $REPO_DIRECTORY/usr/local; games/you-sn-app`

Here is a project with this function: https://github.com/atorresbr/a-la-popa

Here is an image with the example:

[image: Here is an image with the example.]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).